# Android - Using outputstream and Mat buffer to create a mp4 Video

Tags: android, video, mp4, outputstream

I have a buffer which has the Mats from which i want to create a video

I transform those mats into byte array and write them to the outputstream
 yet for some reason whenever I watch the video only one image is shown heres the code

```
try {

    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/ran");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "goal_ran.mp4");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

    for(int i=0;i<buffer.size();i++)
    {

        Mat mat = buffer.get(i);
        MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
        Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", mat, matOfByte);
        byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
        out.write(byteArray);
        out.flush();
        /*byte[] return_buff = new byte[(int) (buffer.get(i).total() * buffer.get(i).elemSize())];
        buffer.get(i).get(0, 0, return_buff);*/
        /*int length = (int) (mat.total() * mat.elemSize());
        byte buffer[] = new byte[length];
        mat.get(0, 0, buffer);
        out.write(buffer);*/
    }

    out.close();
    Log.d("Video","Successful"+ buffer.size());



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```